# call a callback function in a pthread function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning about callback functions in C++ and I'm trying to call a callback function in a pthread function wherein I'm passing the function as argument to `pthread_create` using `reinterpret_cast` and then cast it back inside pthread function. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


std::atomic<int32_t> res(0);
using TCallback = std::function<void (int32_t)>;

void put_result(int32_t result) {
    res = result;
}

void time_consuming_func(TCallback Callback) {
    sleep(10);
    int32_t result = 10456456;
    Callback(result);
}

void* thread_func(void* arg) {
    TCallback callback = std::bind(reinterpret_cast<void (*) (int32_t)>(arg), std::placeholders::_1);
    time_consuming_func(callback);

    return nullptr;
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t p1;
    pthread_create(&p1, nullptr, thread_func, reinterpret_cast<void*>(put_result));
    
    std::cout << "before: " << res << std::endl;
    pthread_join(p1, nullptr);
    std::cout << "after: " << res << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm trying to compile the above program with the command `g++ -Wall -pedantic-errors func_callback_demo.cpp -o func_callback_demo -std=c++11 -lpthread` and it doesn't work, but if I remove `-pedantic-errors` and `-wall` flags it compiles.

Can somebody tell why this difference?

Comment: C++11 has threading as part of the language (depending on the platform, may very well be implemented in terms of pthread), no need to use pthread directly.

Comment: ..and passing functions to be called from the thread is one thing that is so much easier when using `std::thread`

Comment: @Eljay Yeah I know that. Right now I'm just trying to do the same using pthread directly

Comment: C++11 changed the C++ abstract machine to accommodate threading in many big ways (like... adding threading!), and in many subtle ways (such as order of operations and memory ordering and coherency).  Has using the pthread API directly taken into account the differences in the modern C++ abstract machine from the prior (C++98) abstract machine?  (I haven't used pthread directly since the 1990s, so I'm out of touch.)

Comment: Please provide the error message(s).

Comment: @G.M. `ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Werror=pedantic]
  TCallback callback = std::bind(reinterpret_cast<void (*) (int32_t)>(arg), std::placeholders::_1);` and another same error while calling `pthread_create`

Comment: This cast is non-portable, but somewhat allowed, see http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8 . You can avoid it with a level of indirection, by storing the function pointer in an object/variable and passing the address of that object instead. Beware of lifetime issues, the caller might remove that object before the thread has used it!

Comment: Woah, is that a gcc 4.8? That's a bit old. 4.9+ accept this conversion: https://godbolt.org/z/8ErYTa

Comment: @dyp gcc version 4.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can somebody tell why this difference?

Casting between a pointer-to-function and a pointer-to-object types is not portable. Compilers *might* accept it, or they might reject it. See C++ Standard [expr.reinterpret.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8)

GCC is a bit inconsistent here: up to but excluding gcc 4.9, you get a warning with `-pedantic` about this cast. If you enable `-pedantic-errors`, this warning turns into an error. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64531 though I failed to find a specific bug report on this.

Starting with GCC 4.9, you don't get a warning for such a cast.

Still, the cast is not entirely portable. There are architectures on which pointer-to-object and pointer-to-function have different sizes (Itanium, for example). If you want perfect portability, avoid the cast. You can, for example, put the pointer-to-function into an object and pass the address of that object to `pthread_create`:

```
using put_result_t = decltype(put_result);
put_result_t* arg = &put_result;
pthread_create(&p1, nullptr, thread_func, &arg);
```

This requires however for `arg` to live at least until the created thread has performed its last read from `arg`. You can ensure this by joining the created thread, or passing ownership to the created thread, like:

```
using put_result_t = decltype(put_result);
put_result_t** arg = new put_result_t*{&put_result};
pthread_create(&p1, nullptr, thread_func, arg); // thread must delete arg!
```

Usually, you would embed all arguments into a struct, and use a wrapper function around the provided thread function to manage lifetime (= copying, deletion). Or similarly with stateful lambdas.

```
auto func = [/*can capture additional state here*/]{
    time_consuming_func(put_result);
};

// move func to heap
auto* func_on_heap = new auto{std::move(func)};

// pthread adapter
auto pthread_adapter = [](void* arg) {
    // Restore type of argument, and put into unique_ptr for exception safety
    // Well, the program would abort if an exception escapes here..
    std::unique_ptr<decltype(func)> restored_func_on_heap{
        static_cast<decltype(func_on_heap)>(arg)
    };

    (*restored_func_on_heap)();

    return nullptr;
}

// using implicit conversion from decltype(pthread_adapter) to void*(*)(void*),
// and from decltype(func)* to void*
pthread_create(&p1, nullptr,
               /* void*(*)(void*) */ pthread_adapter,
               /* (void*)         */ func_on_heap);
```

---

There are some points where your code could be improved, I suggest posting it on codereview.stackexchange.com at some point.